# Spring MVC - Multiple submit button to a Form

Tags: java, spring, controller

I am trying to have 2 submit buttons post to a form, with each button action mapped to different controllers. Here are my mappings

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST, params="save")
@RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST, params="renew")
```

And my submit buttons look like these -

```
<input type="submit" name="save" class="button" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" name="renew" class="button" value="Renew" />
```

As you can see from my mapping, I am relying on the use of params to differentiate what button was clicked on. The problem is that it works 90% of the time but sometimes I get the exception below -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8090/myapp/save': {public java.lang.String com.myapp.SaveController.save(MyEntity,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession), public java.lang.String com.myapp.SaveController.saveAndRenew(MyEntity,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)}
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:248)
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:194)
```

Strangely, when this happens and I re-submit the page, everything works fine afterwards. Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do ?

Thanks!

Comment: not sure if its your problem, but keep in mind some browsers wont send the key/value pair of any buttons if the user submits the form via enter key or certain other methods besides clicking the button. So, make sure to assume a default action, which, for browser compatibility needs to be the action of the *first button* in the html source of that form.

Answer (score 40):

if the form has these buttons specified:

```
input type="submit" class="button" name="save" value="Save"
input type="submit" class="button" name="delete" value="Delete"
input type="submit" class="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel"
```

you may direct to different url request according to button pressed with one controller.

for cancel button,

```
@RequestMapping(params = "cancel", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String cancelUpdateUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "redirect:/users.html";
}
```

what request mapping does is to scan post request if it contains params name = cancel.

for save button,

```
@RequestMapping(params = "save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUser(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute User user, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    // validate your result
    // if no errors, save it and redirect to successView.
}
```

Answer (score 36):

Why not:

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="save" />
```

and then:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String handlePost(@RequestParam String action){

    if( action.equals("save") ){
       //handle save
    }
    else if( action.equals("renew") ){
       //handle renew
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems a bit dangerous, as the `value` attribute on `input` tag contains the text of the button. I think i18n won't be your friend with this method.

Comment: I had problems with IE (10) not posting values consistently, & adopted your approach. Whilst not ultra-clean, it worked for me.  Cheers.

Answer (score 10):

If You have more controller methods with the same `@RequestMapping` that differs only in `params` attribute, You have to explicitly write:

- which parameter is supposed to be present in the request, e.g. `params="save"`
- which parameter is NOT supposed to be present in the request, e.g. `params="!save"`

In Your case:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST, params={"save", "!renew"})
@RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST, params={"renew", "!save"})
```

This should fix error **Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path ...**

See [Spring Web API 4.0.x - RequestMapping#params](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--)

Answer (score 7):

Just create one controller with a method similar to this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String handlePost(@RequestParam(required=false , value = "save") String saveFlag , @RequestParam(required=false , value = "renew") String renewFlag){

if(saveFlag != null{
   //handle save
}
else if(renewFlag !=null{
   //handle renew
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

One more solution:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save", method={RequestMethod.POST}, params={"save=Save"})
@RequestMapping(value="/save", method={RequestMethod.POST}, params={"renew=Renew"})
```