# Is there a way to differentiate methods with @RequestAnnotations with same parameters in Spring Web MVC?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, methods, annotations

I entered in **Spring Web MVC Framework** not long ago thus I am a complete beginner.

The issue I have is the following.
I have a file named *myForm.jsp* where am I presenting some text, tables, etc. . Besides that I have also **2 froms with two appropriate buttons** (*see the code below*).

---

```jsp
<!-- code -->
<form:form id="form1" method="post" commandName="firstForm">
    <!-- code -->
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</form:form>

<!-- code -->

<form:form id="form2" method="post" commandName="secondForm">
    <!-- code -->
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Save" name="save"/>
</form:form>
<!-- code -->
```

---

Now I am interested in handling both submit actions in a **FromController.java**

```java
package si.src.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;

import si.src.forms.Obrazec;

@Controller
public class ObrazecFormController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/spletniObrazec", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitTheFromButton1(){
         //logic for button1
         //additional code
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/spletniObrazec", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitTheFromButton2(){
         //logic for button2
         //additional code
    }   
}
```

---

Is there a way how to tell Spring to distinguish between two methods? Perhaps with additional **@annotations** or **name/value** properties in form:form tag?

I also tried writing different controller classes but it doesn't work since this Spring MVC is behaving in a event-driven manner.

Probably I am missing the whole concept of controllers, methods and annotations so I will really appreciate any advice/idea/suggestion/solution.

Comment: You should read up on how browsers serialized `<form>` `<input>` elements when submitting a form.

Answer (score 0):

You should use different actions into forms, can see a tutorial here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm

or here:
[Spring MVC - Multiple submit button to a Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954426/spring-mvc-multiple-submit-button-to-a-form)