# Spring get clicked button in Java-Class

Tags: java, spring

I have following problem: I have two buttons **accept** and **decline**. In my Controller-Class i want to know, which button were clicked. i solved this in a way, which is bad i think. Each button got his own form, so that i can see which button was triggered.

```
<form method="post" action="save">
    <input type="hidden" name="accept" th:value="true" />
    <button type="submit" name="accepted" id="modalAcceptTrigger"
        class="btn btn-lg myBtn_accept" title="Auftrag annehmen">
        Annehmen
    </button>
</form>
<form method="post" action="save">
    <input type="hidden" name="decline" th:value="false" />
    <button type="submit" name="declined" id="modalDeclineTrigger"
        class="btn btn-lg myBtn_decline" title="Auftrag abgelehnt">
        Ablehnen
    </button>
</form>
```

In my class i get the hidden input field and know which button was pressed.

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public String saveJob(@RequestParam(value = "accept") Boolean accept) {

    if (accept) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

My question is now: How can i make only one **form** and get the triggered button in my java class? Does anybody know and can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954426/spring-mvc-multiple-submit-button-to-a-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have just have one form with 2 buttons as you say. Before submitting the form I would have a js function executed that changes the input hidden value decline/accept. So I would

```
<form method="post" id="save-form" action="save">
    <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" />
    <button type="button" name="declined" id="modalDeclineTrigger"
        class="btn btn-lg myBtn_decline" title="Auftrag abgelehnt">
        Ablehnen
    </button>
    <button type="button" name="accepted" id="modalAcceptTrigger"
        class="btn btn-lg myBtn_accept" title="Auftrag annehmen">
        Annehmen
    </button>
</form>
```

And the js: (That should be place within an on document ready)

```
<script>
$('#modalAcceptTrigger').on('click', function(){$('#action').val('decline'); $('#save-form').submit();});
$('#modalDeclineTrigger').on('click', function(){$('#action').val('accept'); $('#save-form').submit();});
</script>
```

And the controller should expect an ENUM {decline, accept} rather than a boolean

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It works, but it is not an ENUM in the controller, but a String.

Answer (score 1):

Leave just one form with hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" name="userAction" th:value="true" />
```

add a script to set the `userAction` to `true` or `false` depending on clicked option before submitting form (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053394/how-to-do-something-before-on-submit)).

and in the controller

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public String saveJob(@RequestParam(value = "userAction") Boolean accept)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, i will try!